# After resource creation in terraform framework i want to display message to the user

Tags: terraform

After method

```
func (r *vmResource) Create(ctx context.Context, req resource.CreateRequest, resp *resource.CreateResponse)
```

has finished creating resource i would like to display a message to the user.

Trying to display message